# Drag & drop interface for files?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface

I have a simple script that displays filenames

```
import os
path = "C:\\temp\\somefiles\\"
theFiles = os.listdir(path)
for f in theFiles:
  print(f)
```

`bak.txt gwen.bat spoon_01.jpg spoon_02.jpg`

So far so good. Instead of hardcoding the pathname, I want to be able to drag & drop the files I want to process onto a minimalist desktop widget. What are my options with Python?

Comment: you should have a look a tkinter and specifically askdirectory widget may be of use

Comment: If it's windows,  you could add your python script to the 'open with' list and you don't need your own interface at all.

Comment: @jeffUK I am using Windows, can you elaborate further, please.

Comment: On Windows if you drag & drop files and/or folders onto a Python script, they will automatically be appended to the end of `sys.argv` list when it runs. You can use `os.path.isdir()` to test whether an element in the list is a directory.

Comment: Sorry, I mean 'Send To...'  you can put your python file in the 'send to' list, then it allows you to send any file into your widget from explorer/desktop etc.  Works the same way as dragging the file onto the .py file as @martineau mentions, but it's more easily accessible

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/139968/how-to-add-an-item-to-my-send-to-context-menu

Comment: If you want a bit of GUI  you can use the `FileDialog` from **wxPython**

Answer (score 2):

As per the comments, in windows you can drag a file onto a .py file and it will execute with the files in the sys.argv variable

```
import sys
theFiles = sys.argv[1:] #argv[0] is the script itself.
for f in theFiles:
  print(f)
input("Press Any Key to Continue")
```

Putting your .py file in the windows 'SendTo' directory allows you to do this from the right-click menu